# How to replace path in Vuejs router?

Tags: vue.js, routes

`Bar` is in Navbar so can be clicked from any paths. When I click it `bar/:lang/:someId` concat to the previous path. As an example I get `foo2/bar/en/223344` as path. How can I manage it to get exactly `bar/:lang/:someId` path?

```
routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    name: 'home'
  },
  {
    path: 'foo',
    component: () => {'@/views/Foo.vue'},
    children: [
      {
        path: 'bar/:lang/:someId',
        name: 'bar',
        component: () => {'@/views/Bar.vue'}
      }
    ]
   },
   {
    path: 'foo2',
    component: () => {'@/views/Foo2.vue'},
    children: [
      {
        path: 'bar2/:lang/:someId',
        name: 'bar2',
        component: () => {'@/views/Bar2.vue'}
      }
    ]
   }
 ]
```

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    goTo(lang, id) {
      this.$router.push({
        path: `bar/${lang}/${id}`
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <div @click="goTo('en', '223344')">Go to page</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace home path from empty string to slash '/' and put all nested routes in the children of the parent route. It should look like this:

`routes = [ { path: '/', name: 'home', children: [ ...your routes ] } ]`

Comment: I can't change the structure of routes in my project. There are lots of routes...

Comment: You just need to Copy & Paste the routes that should start from the root to the children of the home route.
I don't think this is a problem, no matter how many routes you have